# How to create a Top 10 Popular Posts Page?

Tags: posts

I need to create a "Popular Posts Page", that shows the Top 10 most viewed posts of all the time, based on the high number of views.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start (Function found [here](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/track-post-views-without-a-plugin-using-post-meta/#));

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}

// Remove issues with prefetching adding extra views
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

Now add this to your single.php file to track views;

```
<?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

Now you can use the meta field `post_views_count` to create a simple WP_Query loop that shows the 10 posts with the highest number of views. Eg;

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$top_posts = new WP_Query($args);
while ($top_posts->have_posts()) : $top_posts->the_post();
    // Your post loop content
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thank you @Dean Elliot! I have added the code as above, though snippets 1 & 2 seems to be fine for me. Snippet no.3 is a little of a nightmare as I'm not quite fit for the Wp_queries loops yet. Can you be more specific? I have added the 3rd snippet in the custom post field but nothing happened.

Comment: This is my snippet though: 
$args = array(
       'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => 10,
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
       'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
       'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
       'paged' => $paged,
   'order' => 'DESC'
   );
   $hot_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  ?>

  <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'post' ); ?>

  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $hot_query->have_posts() ) : $hot_query->the_post(); ?>

  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

Comment: @Frank I've updated the third step of my answer.

Comment: @Frank this will echo the view count on the front-end `<?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>`

Comment: Wow @Dean ! It seems to work perfect so far. How can I also show the number of views under each post/link in the loop? EG: Link no.1-80 Views, Link no.2-70 Views ect.

Comment: All is working smoothly. The only issue is with the first (top - most viewed) link. Each time I refresh the Popular posts page it increases the top one of one view count. I have added: 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, but didn't work. Anyway, you are great! Thank you so much mate. This is such a huge help from you! Appreciate a lot.

Comment: @Frank Without seeing the complete query / file it'd be hard to troubleshoot that one. Best of luck with it all.